# Insert data loop

Tags: php, jquery, combobox, insert

I have a problems in inserting the data with loop in PHP. I want to Insert the "STATUS MATAKULIAH" and "KODE MATAKULIAH" consisting of two or more data into db_unifa.tdkrs tables. I don't know how to do this. Maybe anyone here can help me to solve my problem.
Here is my code:

```
<html>
//table head start
<table id="tableData" width='1028' border='1'>
    <tr class="head">
        <th width='32'><div align='center'><strong>STATUS MATAKULIAH</strong></div></th>
        <th width='216'><div align='center'><strong>KODE MATAKULIAH</strong></div></th>
        <th width='616'><div align='center'><strong>NAMA MATAKULIAH</strong></div></th>
        <th width='60'><div align='center'><strong>SKS</strong></div></th>
        <th width='30'><div align='center'><strong>PILIH</strong></div></th>
    </tr>
//table head end

//retrieve data td from database start
<?php $sqlkk = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT stambuk FROM tnilaikkrekap WHERE stambuk=$_SESSION[stambuk]");
        $i = 1;
        while($hasilkk = mysql_fetch_array($sqlkk))
            if($hasilkk > 0){
                    //mahasiswa korban konversi kurikulum
                $sql_isi = mysql_query("SELECT tregmk.kmk,tmmatakuliah.nmk,ifnull(tmmatakuliah.sks,0) AS sks FROM tregmk JOIN tmmatakuliah 
                                ON (tregmk.kmk=tmmatakuliah.kmk) LEFT JOIN v_all_nilai_kk ON ((tregmk.kmk=v_all_nilai_kk.kmk) AND 
                                (v_all_nilai_kk.stambuk=$_SESSION[stambuk]) AND (v_all_nilai_kk.nilai > 2)) WHERE (tregmk.tahunajarn=$thajaran) 
                                and (tregmk.semester=$smster) AND (tregmk.fakultas=$fakpilihan) AND (tregmk.prodi=$prodi) AND (tregmk.jenjang=$jenjang) AND 
                                (v_all_nilai_kk.kmk is null) AND (tmmatakuliah.nokur=$no_kur)");
                while($hasil_isi = mysql_fetch_array($sql_isi)){
                    $j = $hasil_isi[sks];
                    echo    "<tr class='genap'>";
                    echo        "<td align='center'><select name='statuskmk$i'><option name='baru$i' value='0'>Baru</option>
                                <option name='ulang' value='1'>Ulang</option><option name='perbaikan' value='3'>Perbaikan</option><option>Batal</option>
                                </select></td>";
                    echo        "<td>$hasil_isi[kmk]</td>";
                    echo        "<td>$hasil_isi[nmk]</td>";
                    echo        "<td align='center'>$hasil_isi[sks]</td>";
                    echo        "<td><div align='center'>";
                    echo            "<input type='checkbox' id='id$i' name='statmk$i' value='$j'></input>";
                    echo        "</div></td>";
                    echo    "</tr>";
                    $i++;
                }
            } ?> </table> 
//retrieve data end

//Insert data with while loop start
<?php
if($_POST['simpan']){
    $tajaran = $_POST['thajaran'];
    $semester = $_POST['sms'];
    $fakultas = $_POST['fak'];
    $propil = $_POST['pstudi'];
    $jenpil = $_POST['jenjang'];
    $ins_nid = $_POST['kdpa'];
    $ins_iplalu = $_POST['ips'];
    $ins_skscp = $_POST['csks'];
    $ins_sksrc = $_POST['rsks'];
    $ins_sksambil = $_POST['sksambil'];
    $ins_ipk = $_POST['ipk'];
    $ins_konsen = $_POST['konsent'];
    $user = $_POST['nmmhs'];
    $tanggal = $_POST['tanggal'];
    $kdmk = $_POST['kdmk'];
    $status = $_POST['myselect'];
    include "konek.php";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($kmk); $i++){
    $insert = "INSERT INTO db_unifa.tdkrs (tdkrs.idkrs,tdkrs.kmk,tdkrs.statskmk,tdkrs.tanggal,tdkrs.user)
               VALUES('$tajaran$semester$fakultas$propil$jenpil$_SESSION[stambuk]','$kdmk$i',left($status,1),$tanggal,'$user')";
    $query = mysql_query($insert);
    }
        if ($query) {
        echo "<script>alert('Data berhasil disimpan !')</script>";
        //echo "<script>window.location.href = 'data.php?cabang=$cabang'</script>";
        }
        else { 
        echo "<script>alert('Error: Data gagal dimasukkan!')</script>";
        }
}
?>
//Insert data with while loop end
```

Please help.

Comment: What's your question? Database or text?

Comment: My question is two. First, I want to get combobox value and show it into text. When I checked the checkbox then combobox value appeared into text. Second, I want to insert all of this into database. What should I do? Please help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>sample Page</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var szTr;
        szTr = szTr + "<tr class='genap'>";
        szTr = szTr + "<td align='center'><select name='statuskmk$i'><option name='baru$i' value='0'>Baru</option>"
        szTr = szTr + "<option name='ulang' value='1'>Ulang</option><option name='perbaikan' value='3'>Perbaikan</option><option>Batal</option>"
        szTr = szTr + "/select></td>";
        szTr = szTr + "<td>$hasil_isi[kmk]</td>";
        szTr = szTr + "<td>$hasil_isi[nmk]</td>";
        szTr = szTr + "<td align='center'>$hasil_isi[sks]</td>";
        szTr = szTr + "<td><div align='center'>";
        szTr = szTr + "<input type='checkbox' id='checkid' name='statmk' value='sample'></input>";
        szTr = szTr + "</div></td>";
        szTr = szTr + "</tr>";


        $('#tableData').append(szTr)


        $('#test').click(function () {
            $('#tableData tr').find('td input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
                // alert($(this).attr('value'))

                $('#result_value').val($(this).closest('tr').find('select').val())
                $('#result_text').val($(this).closest('tr').find('select option:selected').text())
            });
        });




    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="test" value="GetChecked Value"/><br />
   selected combo value <input type="text" id="result_value"/><br />
   selected combotext  <input type="text" id="result_text"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <table id="tableData" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">


    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, tbody exist. this working but not like what I mean.
I want to get combobox value when checkbox is checked and show combobox value into text but not checkbox value.

Comment: I hope you have another suggest @Shriya R. :-)

Comment: @waterfall check now :)

Comment: Wow. it's awesome. You're greatest @Shriya R. It Works :-) Thanks

Comment: Please let me ask you again. I'm still got confused with my code. Do you know how to Insert data to database where data from while loop? I want to insert that data into my database.

Comment: retrieve data from table??

Comment: No. I want to Insert data into database. I'll update my code above.

Comment: Only the last value get into the database. What should I do to Insert all of the require data into database?
Any suggest @Shriya R. Need help

Comment: Php code?? Or just want to get all table row data for posting??

Comment: with php code @Shriya R. I want to insert all of that data into database. But my problem is I can't insert all of them. Any suggest?

Comment: I have this following array code: <input type="text" id="id$i" name="name$i" /> And I want to insert them into database with POST method. I put $i after id to create unique id. I make $i from for loop with $i = 1; $i++. So, the result will be like this: <input type="text" id="id1" name="name1" /> <input type="text" id="id2" name="name2" /> etc. So, my question is what can I do if I want to insert this data with POST method.? Pleasee help @Shriya R